# How do I get the window id and tab number of a Terminal window using AppleScript via the ScriptingBridge?

Tags: cocoa, applescript, appleevents, scripting-bridge

I can open a Terminal tab using the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set myTab to do script "exec sleep 1"
    get myTab
end tell
```

This returns a string like: `tab 1 of window id 3263 of application "Terminal"`. This is great, I can see the window id *3263* and tab number *1* (although I don't know how to query *myTab* to get only these values).

In the Cocoa ScriptingBridge, I can do:

```
SBApplication  *terminal;
SBObject       *tab;

terminal = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.terminal"]
tab = [terminal doScript:@"exec sleep 1" in:nil]
```

*How do I get the window id and tab number from the tab object?*

---

**Edit 2009/4/27 - Why?**

In answer to why I want to do this - I am opening a command in a Terminal window (as above), and am getting back the *tab* object. However I want to move/resize this window, so I need to get access to the tab's "window" object.

I am using Objective-C (well actually, Objective-C bridged from Perl), and want to stick to standard OS components, so I believe I only have the NSAppleScript and ScriptingBridge frameworks to play with (all the perl applescript modules broke with 64bit carbon removal). I would try NSAppleScript, but processing the returned values seems to be a black-art.

My current solution is to get the *TTY* of the tab object (guaranteed unique) and enumerate every tab of every window until I find the window containing the tab. I assumed that this couldn't be the best way (it sure ain't fast!).

---

**Edit 2009/4/30 - Solution**

Based on the suggestions of "[has](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199960/has)" below, I braved the [NSAppleEventDescriptor](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAppleEventDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAppleEventDescriptor/descriptorForKeyword:) API. Initially, I was only able to get to this with NSAppleScript's `executeAndReturnError()` call. However I found that NSAppleScript was much, much slower than ScriptingBridge.

After using [ClassDump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) to extract some more SBObject calls, I found the undocumented `specifierDescription()` and `qualifiedSpecifier()` calls. The former gives me the nice "*tab X of window id Y*" string. The latter returns the apple event descriptor, which I can then decode.

My final code (in perl) is:

```
use Foundation;

NSBundle->bundleWithPath_('/System/Library/Frameworks/ScriptingBridge.framework')->load;

# Create an OSType (bid endian long) from a string
sub OSType ($) { return unpack('N', $_[0]) }

my $terminal = SBApplication->applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.terminal");

my $tab         = $terminal->doScript_in_("exec sleep 1", undef);
my $tab_ev_desc = $tab->qualifiedSpecifier;
my $tab_id      = $tab_ev_desc->descriptorForKeyword_(OSType 'seld')->int32Value;
my $win_ev_desc = $tab_ev_desc->descriptorForKeyword_(OSType 'from');
my $window_id   = $win_ev_desc->descriptorForKeyword_(OSType 'seld')->int32Value;

print "Window:$window_id Tab:$tab_id\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can't; a better question is why do want to?

(Well, okay, you could if you use the Apple Event Manager API or [objc-appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net), both of which can give you a raw AEDesc/NSAppleEventDescriptor which you can recursively [pull apart yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247013/how-to-extract-applescript-data-from-a-nsappleeventdescriptor-in-cocoa-and-parse). Or you might poke around in SB to see if there's an undocumented API to get at the underlying AEDesc, but caveat emptor, of course. Alternatively, there may be a better way to achieve your actual goal without resorting to hackery, but you'd need to provide more information.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated the question to add the "why" part. I suspected I might end up messing with the AppleEvents. Is this possible in NSAppleScript? I am trying to work with only things that a re preinstalled on the machine.

Comment: Yeah, should've thought of NSAppleScript too. If you run your 'do script' command in AppleScript using -[NSAppleScript executeAppleEvent:error:] (assuming you want to pass in parameters as well) and return the reference, you'll get an NSAppleEventDescriptor containing your object specifier. Bit messy, but if you're not in [Obj-]C and can't afford external dependencies then it's really your only option. As for packing and unpacking AEDescs, it's not too hard once you know how they're structured. e.g. Take a look at objc-appscript's AEMCodecs class for tips.

Comment: Thanks - it appears that the NSAppleEventDescriptor is the way to go. Since I didn't like the performance of NSAppleScript, I found an undocumented ScriptingBridge call that returned the descriptor. I added my code to the end of the question.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I just had this problem today, and I found no good answers online. This worked for me:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set newTab to do script "echo hello"
    set theWindow to first window of (every window whose tabs contains newTab)
    set windowId to theWindow's id
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of theWindow's tabs
        if item i of theWindow's tabs is newTab then set tabNumber to i
    end repeat
    get {windowId, tabNumber}
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something very simple like this:

tell application "Terminal"
    set new_win to do script ""
    set w_id to id of front window
end tell

Comment: Yes, I used that for a while, but there is a race condition if the user switched windows between the "do script" and the "set id", which happens more than you would initially expect.