# NSAppleEventDescriptor to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript

I'm trying to create an `NSArray` with list values from an `NSAppleEventDescriptor`. There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247013/how-to-extract-applescript-data-from-a-nsappleeventdescriptor-in-cocoa-and-parse) asked some years back, although the solution returns an `NSString`.

```
NSString *src = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"return {\"foo\", \"bar\", \"baz\"}\n"];
NSAppleScript *exe = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:src];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *desc = [exe executeAndReturnError:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", desc);

// <NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 'utxt'("foo"), 'utxt'("bar"), 'utxt'("baz") ]>
```

I'm not sure what descriptor function I need that will parse the values into an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The returned event descriptor must be coerced to a list descriptor.
Then you can get the values with a repeat loop.

```
NSString *src = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"return {\"foo\", \"bar\", \"baz\"}\n"];
NSAppleScript *exe = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:src];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *desc = [exe executeAndReturnError:nil];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *listDescriptor = [desc coerceToDescriptorType:typeAEList];
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= [listDescriptor numberOfItems]; ++i) {
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *stringDescriptor = [listDescriptor descriptorAtIndex:i];
    [result addObject: stringDescriptor.stringValue];
}
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an extension to make this easier.

Note that `atIndex()` / `descriptorAtIndex:` has **1-based indexes**.

```
extension NSAppleEventDescriptor {
    
    func listItems() -> [NSAppleEventDescriptor]? {
        guard descriptorType == typeAEList else { return nil }
        guard numberOfItems > 0 else { return [] }
        return Array(1...numberOfItems).compactMap({ atIndex($0) })
    }
    
}
```

Please comment or edit if any improvements can be made!

Comment: An Objective-C version would be great as well, thanks!

Comment: Make sure in the AppleScript you return an array